# Is it okay for a resolver to have side effects besides resolving the type?

Tags: graphql

When creating a GraphQL mutation or query, you usually retrieve or save data. But let's assume I would like to send an e-mail when the data is saved or perform some additional side effects.

Is it common practice for resolvers to have these kind of side effects? Since resolvers should only resolve data according to the SOLID principle, right?

If it turns out that the resolver should not have side effects like these, then where would the side effects belong?

Most tutorials and articles online, including the official tutorial of GraphQL itself, don't seem to cover this or take it into account.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on that resolver is resolving fields of what types.

If it is resolving the fields of the root mutation ,it must involve sides effects as mutation is supposed to modify server-side data. So it is okay to send an email in root mutation field 's resolver.

For the resolver of object type and root query fields , as it is supposed to only retrieving data, it is awkward for me if they have any side effects.

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification!